# Is your comment on another person's public photo always published on your wall?

Tags: photos, facebook, comments

If not, in what circumstances would it not appear?

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be divided into two parts: Timeline and Non-Timeline. Let's start with Non-Timeline first [that is, you don't have Facebook Timeline profile yet]

**Non-Timeline:**

Your comment will appear on your wall regardless of the photo being public or private.

However, if it's a **public** photo, all friends will see your comment on the photo.
If it's **private**, only you will be able to see it or only mutual friends of whose photo you commented on, will be able to see the published comment activity on your wall.

**Timeline:**

Your comments don't appear on the wall, regardless of it being private or public. But it can pop-up in the news feed and friends can see it depending on the privacy settings as outlined above.

However, you can see all your comments [and other activities] by clicking the `Activity Log` button.